# Как определить порядок символов в строке

Tags: java, строки

Есть строка состоящая из чисел, которые разделены пробелом, одно число не может быть больше 100. Мне надо проверить что введенные числа разделены только одним пробелом. Если пробел один, возвращаю true, если больше одного, то возвращаю false. Проверку на то что в строке только цифры и пробелы я сделал, а вот с количеством пробелов не получается. Вот то, что смог написать:

```
private static boolean checkDigital(String word)throws Exception{
        if (word == null)
            throw new Exception("Not text");

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            if (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != ' '){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Подскажите, как правильно провалидировать количество пробелов между числами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char previousChar = '.';
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    char c = word.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != ' '){
        return false;
    }
    if (c == ' ' && c == previousChar) {
        return false;
    }
    previousChar = c;
}
```

Comment: в моём случае после цифрового символа должен идти пробел, а потом снова цифровой символ... char previousChar = '.'; сразу выдаст false

Comment: `char previousChar = '.'` - это просто присвоение символа, который не пробел, ничего оно возвратить не может. А условие `(c == ' ' && c == previousChar)` вернёт `false` только в том случае, если и текущий символ и предыдущий равны пробелу, что возможно только при двух пробелах подряд.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Теперь надо разобраться в сути этого решения. Просто и работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static boolean checkDigital(String word)throws Exception{
    if (word == null) throw new Exception("Not text");
    char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();
    boolean isSpace = false;
    for (char ch : charArray) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) isSpace = false;
        else if (ch == ' ') {
            if (isSpace) return false;
            isSpace = true;
        }
        else return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Таким образом можно проверить, что строка содержит только цифры, разделенные одинарным пробелом. Во всех остальных случаях вернет false